# IIS Session State default values

Tags: iis, session-state, iis-10

I enabled ASP.net on IIS World wide web services. I wanted to configure session state using the GUI application and see how it reflects on the site's web.config.

Is the default value of CookieSettings mode UseCookies? 
If yes, where is it being inherited from? I checked the root level web.config and I couldn't find any value for session state.

Can I know how it is happening?

Comment: Not able to find in machine.config. I thought Microsoft would never hard-code anything! :|

Comment: Microsoft clearly documented the settings and their default values https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/h6bb9cz9%28v%3dvs.85%29